# remote neo4j data base: import large amount of data

Tags: import, neo4j

I need to import about one million of nodes and rougly twice as many relationships between them to a remote neo4j database. 
The thing that matters to me is: performance

I found the [java-rest-binding](https://github.com/neo4j/java-rest-binding) which seems to offer just what I need. However:

- it's too slow (about 1000 nodes / second, even if the remote database is in fact on my local machine)
- it's buggy, i.e. it just hangs on committing the batch operation if I try to add more than ~900 nodes at once

How could I achieve the speed I need? 
And, why the java-rest-binding not working / slow?

(I would like to avoid having to deal with HTTP requests and such myself, as it is suggested [here in the docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-batch-ops.html))

I'm happy to post code or more details. just tell me!

Thanks a lot for your help!

Nandaloo

Comment: Maybe the BatchInserter (http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/batchinsert.html) can be of help here.

Comment: To my understanding the normal BatchInserter works only on embedded databases. However, in my case, I don't have an embedded but and remote database. So it won't work. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: This seems to be the case indeed. Maybe it's an option to insert your initial data into an embedded database and use this database later on in you Neo4j REST server? Don't know whether that's possible, but I guess so.

Comment: This would technically be possible. But the productive system will have larger updates concerning relations and I would not want to shutdown the whole system for that. The original reason for using the Neo4j server was to not being forced to shutdown the system for updates.

Comment: I've read a thing or two about Neo4j using a binary protocol which should speed things up. This is thing only remaining thing I can think of that might help you. Good luck!

Comment: @nandaloo I'm curious, have you succeeded with inserting lots of data into remote Neo4j?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done some insertion tests as well, and the max I got (without going a lot into fine optimizations) was something like 500 nodes with 10 properties + 500 relationships / s

I am not sure you can go beyond what you already got (1000 nodes / s) using the REST interface. You could probably try using a custom extension that would probably go faster than the REST API, provided that the data to load is local if you cannot shutdown your DB and use the BatchInserter (which is very very fast btw).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I already thought about writing a server plugin and define my own bulk-format. My data just has to flow within a single LAN, network speed is not a problem here. Did you mean such a plugin when you said "custom extension"? I would think of this: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-plugins.html

Comment: Yes, a server plugin was what I meant by "custom extension". I think this could work, although I didn't try it myself.

Answer (score 1):

How is your remote database setup? Are you hosting an embedded `Neo4j` instance inside of other code, such as Tomcat? Or is it just a `Neo4j` stand-alone database?

Either way, you could write java code to run on the machine that houses the actual data directory and just manipulate that with the normal `Neo4j` API. This is usually very fast, and allows you more control over things like transaction management. Do note that this will require your `Neo4j` Database to be down, as 2 separate Java processes cannot manipulate the Database at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! The remote database is a standalone neo4j data base. Yes, what you suggest would work, however, this import is done many times so I would like it to be as simple as possible...

Comment: You can use Neo4j's Managed or Unmanaged extensions to perform this, which allow you to import Java classes into the stand-alone server and register your own REST endpoints. You can register 1 call that will trigger the import.

Comment: This is the direction I'm thinking to. I'm not yet quite familiar with Neo4j server extensions, thus one question: Do I only get the possibility to register my own REST endpoint or can I even get access to the original request? If I could get the request, I could send whatever data I want what I would expect to be the most direct way.

Comment: You should have access to most everything you would have for JAX-RS/Jersey annotations